# Android Oauth storing client credentials

Tags: android, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

While I'm testing/writing my app, I have hard-coded my Oauth credentials into my code (username, password, client secret and client id).  How do I obfuscate or store these values in a secure way?  If someone were to decompile (de-dex? is that a thing?) my APK couldn't they see my credentials?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot embed a password in an APK in such a way that it can be extracted (by the program) and cannot be extracted (by peeping eyes). The more interesting questions is: why would you want to?

Comment: I'm syncing data down from my php server using oauth. I'm not ever having the user go through the oauth flow because syncing is handled in the background. They never enter the credentials so they have to be saved somewhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that makes no sense at all. How is the fact that syncing happens in the background related to users not going through an authentication/authorization step? Your server and the data it holds is completely open, if you embed a fixed, non user-dependent password in the APK. As an optimization, consider removing the OAuth layer. That certainly would not make this any less secure.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Of course I want oauth because it prevents unauthorized people from accessing my API. I do follow the oauth flow but it happens in the background and doesn't force the user to login using a website form. I'm using the password grant auth type and I send client_id, client_secret, username/email, and password to request a token. After getting the token, I send the token along with each API call. If I make an API call without a token, the page shows access denied. I'm asking how to include the client_id, client_secret, username, password in the APK securely

Comment: I repeat: you can not include a password in the APK securely. It's there for everyone to take. Using OAuth with a fixed user ID and password provides no security whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

you can break the credential strings into small chunks and sprinkle them throughout your application, and then write code to reconstruct them later into the original values that you need. but while you can make it difficult for someone to discover the credentials you've stored this way, I don't believe you can make it impossible for someone to do so.